# Weighted empirical cumulated distribution plot with latticeExtra

Tags: r, lattice

The excellent [latticeExtra](http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org) package has a function `ecdfplot()`, which creates a [cumulated empirical distribution plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function).

**Reproducable example:**

```
df= data.frame(X= 1:100, W= 100:1)
library(latticeExtra)
ecdfplot(~X, data=df)
```

[image]

**Problem:**

Instead of counting on basis of observations frequency I need to apply weights using the `df$W` variable.

With [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) this can be done:

```
library(Hmisc)
Ecdf(df$X, weights= df$W)
```

[image]

**Question:**

I want to do the same but use the [lattice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/index.html) graph system.

**How can this be done ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `W` is of type integer, the solution is quite straight forward.

```
ecdfplot(~ rep(x= X, times= W), data=df, xlab= "X")
```

[image]